# Ace editor not auto indenting

Tags: ace-editor, auto-indent, pre

I have a string (from a buffer) that I have to put into an ace editor (like a pre tag) but when I add the string ace is not showing any indentation whereas a normal `<pre></pre>` and the console both show all indentation.

In the console I see the indentation!

```
console.log(d.code.toString());
```

[image]

But when I add it to ace:

```
$('#view').html(
    '<pre id="editor">'
+       (d.code.toString().replace(/\>/g,'&gt;').replace(/\</g,'&lt;'))
+   '</pre>'
    );
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `editor.session.setValue(d.code.toString())` instead of using html.

or simply pass option to `ace.edit`

```js
var editor = ace.edit(null, {
    theme: "ace/theme/monokai",
    mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
    value: d.code.toString(),
});
```

then append `editor.container` to the dom

```js
editor.container.id = "editor"
$('#view').append(editor.container)
```